# How to store values at key =0 into nsarray?

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsmutabledictionary

I want to store all the emails into an array. What do I need to do for the same ?

Comment: response{
    0 =     {
    email = "grover@gmail.com";
    firstname = Grover;
    };
    1 =     {
    email = "hems@gmail.com";
    firstname = Gems;
    };
    2 =     {
    email = "rohit@gmail.com";
    firstname = Rohit;
    };
}

Comment: In the same question, I want to get the email and first name of index 2. How can I do that ?

Comment: NSString * email = [[repsonseDict objectForKey:@"yourIndex"]objectForKey:@"email"]] //set "firstname" for name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code and change it according to your requirement

```
    NSMutableDictionery * repsonseDict = [[NSMutableDictionery alloc]init];
    repsonseDict =  [reponseObj objectForKey@"response"];

    NSArray * allKeys = [repsonseDict allKeys];

    NSMutableArray * emailArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for(int i = 0; i < [allKeys count]; i ++ ){

      NSString * numberKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];

     [emailArr addObject:[[repsonseDict objectForKey:numberKey]objectForKey:@"email"]];
    }
```

Comment: I have to match the stored emails to another email. how to go further ? can you help ?

Comment: @Gurp321 you are welcome..you can also up vote as an apericeation if you want :)

Comment: @Gurp321 yes ofc share another array or dict where it is stored

Comment: I have upvoted but since reputations are less so its not visible.

Comment: In the same question, I want to get the email and first name of index 2. How can I do that ?

Comment: NSString * email = [[repsonseDict objectForKey:@"yourIndex"]objectForKey:@"email"]] //set "firstname" for name